# netcoreapp31 vs .net472 conflicts

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

We have an app which is .netcore 3.1 - a console app.

This uses a 3rd party library from Microsoft which internally creates a dispatcher.

Under an output type of net472 this works, howwever with an output type of netcore31 the following error occurs:

```
System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher' from assembly 'WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.'
```

For information:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  <Platforms>AnyCPU;x86</Platforms>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Does anybody know if there is a way to make this work without having to change to the .net framework which causes a host of other issues mainly related to receiving serialized messages from other apps which have a serialization scheme originating in .net core 3.1.

Comment: add `<UseWpf>true</UseWpf>`

Comment: this causes the application to immediately exit @RandRandom - it is a console app (see output type).

Comment: noticed that you said it is a console app, but your third party library tries to use wpf functionality so you will need the wpf libraries, and to do this you have to declare `<UseWpf>` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading?view=net-5.0 - `Contains types to support the Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) threading system.`

Comment: My test application doesn't immediatly exit - https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKTec.png

Comment: @RandRandom the above is using the topshelf service wrapper.  It is as if the message pump is missing or something to hold the application open.  I'll investigate, thanks!

Comment: Core does not have all the libraries that are in Net.  Are you targeting Core 3.1 from Net 4.7.2?  Is error occurring on a machine that has Net 4.7.2 install or a deploy machine?

Answer (score -1):

I had been receiving the same error message, but for my .net core 5.0 testing project. After attempting several other suggestions I ran across this post and used the commented answers to "add true" as well as adding net5.0-windows.

This may not completely map to your use case as you are using a library that should be able to create your dispatcher, but for my dispatcher error this worked.